# parsing json file with hebrew and english with python 3.5

Tags: python, json, parsing, hebrew

my json file, well, part of it look like :

```
[
  {
    "id": 472,
    "name": "אבו גוש",
    "engName": "ABU GHOSH"
  },
  {
    "id": 473,
    "name": "אבו סנאן",
"engName": "ABU SINAN"
  },
  {
     "id": 1342,
    "name": "אבו קורינאת (יישוב)",
    "engName": "ABU QUREINAT"
  },
]
```

etc..

and my part of code look like :

```
with open('israelCities.json') as data_file:
    jsonData = json.loads(data_file.read().encode('utf8'))
    print(jsonData)
```

it failed on second line (jsonData = ....),
i'm new to python and didn't see any similar question about it,
any help will be appreciated

Thanks !!

## EDIT

those two worked perfect for me :

```
 import json
 import urllib.request
 url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/royts/israel-cities/master/israel-cities.json'
 data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
 json.loads(data)
```

And This One :

```
import json
import requests

r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/royts/israel-cities/master/israel-cities.json')
with open('israelCities.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(r.json(), f)


with open('israelCities.json') as f:
json_data = json.load(f)
```

## Thank you !!

Comment: What does failed mean? What error did you get?

Comment: Hi, I don't know why but my original post has been cutted, no error in pycharm

Answer (score 0):

This, from your code: `json.loads(data_file.read().encode('utf8'))` tries to read data from file and then convert it to utf8.

Try this instead: `json.loads(data_file.read(), encoding='utf8')`, which means: read this, which is written as utf8.

Of course, the file should be saved as utf-8 or it won't work.

---

**EDIT:**

With simplified usage, as @mhawke suggested, and using OP's original file, this works:

```
>>> httpresponse = urllib.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/royts/israel-cities/master/israel-cities.json')
>>> json.load(httpresponse)
```

**EDIT 2:**

If you are using **Python 3**, try this instead:

```
>>> import json
>>> import urllib.request
>>> url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/royts/israel-cities/master/israel-cities.json'
>>> data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
>>> json.loads(data)
```

Comment: really don't know how it work you,
it failed on urlopen...
just kicked me out to the 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Section...

Comment: You are probably using **Python 3**. I added a Python 3 example, which also works for me.

Comment: Hi, you new edit worked ! Thank you !, 
is there any chances to make it local ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to tell the `loads` what the encoding is, not try to convert it to an encoding.

so,

```
import json

with open('israelCities.json') as data_file:
    jsonData = json.loads(data_file.read(), encoding='utf-8')
    print(jsonData)
```

will yield

> [{u'engName': u'ABU GHOSH', u'id': 472, u'name': u'\u05d0\u05d1\u05d5 \u05d2\u05d5\u05e9'}, {u'engName': u'ABU SINAN', u'id': 473, u'name': u'\u05d0\u05d1\u05d5 \u05e1\u05e0\u05d0\u05df'}, {u'engName': u'ABU QUREINAT', u'id': 1342, u'name': u'\u05d0\u05d1\u05d5 \u05e7\u05d5\u05e8\u05d9\u05e0\u05d0\u05ea (\u05d9\u05d9\u05e9\u05d5\u05d1)'}]

but only if you have saved **israelCities.json** as 'utf-8' in its encoding first!

Comment: thank you for your reply, don't know why, but even with your code it doesn't work :
        with open('israelCities.json') as data_file:
            jsonData = json.loads(data_file.read(), encoding='utf8')
            print(jsonData)

the json file downloaded from here :
https://github.com/royts/israel-cities

Comment: You need to explicitly save that file as being encoded in `utf-8`. Do you have `vi` or `sublime` or something?

Comment: I did saved it as utf8 with np++, 
Still no luck

Comment: Hmm. That is odd. I pasted the output from just that code in py2.7 and that file saved as utf-8. So when you run what output are you getting?

Comment: with open('JsonProperits2.json') as data_file:
    data_file = <_io.TextIOWrapper name='JsonProperits2.json' mode='r' encoding='cp1255'>

then on line : 
    jsonData = json.loads(data_file.read(), encoding='utf-8')
it kicked out to if __name__ == "__main__":
, without any output, in debug mode with pyChram,
Thanks alot for trying !

Comment: Can you first confirm which Python you are running? Then, can you just run the 'with' block that we are talking about, with the import, as I wrote in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `read()` on the file. Use `json.load()` instead:

```
import json

with open('israelCities.json') as data_file:
    jsonData = json.load(data_file)
```

If the file is UTF8 encoded (and the one in the git repo [israel-cities](https://github.com/royts/israel-cities) is) you don't need to specify the encoding to `json.load()`.

---

**Update**

From comments in other answers it seems that you might be downloading the file from github and saving it. If you make a clone of the repo you should have no problem with the file - it is already UTF8 encoded. If you are unsure you can download the file using the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library and explicitly save it as json:

```
import json
import requests

r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/royts/israel-cities/master/israel-cities.json')
with open('israelCities.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(r.json(), f)
```

Now you should definitely have a file that can be loaded with:

```
with open('israelCities.json') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
```